# In graphics applications, why do shaders get loaded into the application on runtime?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, glsl, shader

Shaders written in for example GLSL are typically loaded into a graphics application at runtime. I am wondering why not just compile the application with the shaders so they will not have to be loaded later. Like this:

```
#define glsl(version, glsl) "#version " #version "\n" #glsl

namespace glsl { namespace vs {
//VERTEX SHADERS
//=========================
// simple VS
//=========================
constexpr GLchar * const simple = glsl(450 core, 
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    }
    );

} namespace fs {
//FRAGMENT SHADERS
//=========================
// simple FS
//=========================
constexpr GLchar * const simple = glsl(450 core,
    out vec4 color;

    void main() {
        color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }       
    );

} }
```

I don't think this would result in too large of an exe file and it would speed up loading times; unless I'm mistaken about how many shaders are used for a typical graphics application. I realize you may want to update shaders after compile time, but does that really happen?

**Is there any reason that I should not want to do this?**

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, since it's likely to generate a large number of opinionated or subjective answers.

Comment: The major reason why I wouldn't do this is because you have to recompile your application whenever a shader is changed. In my current project building the application can take several minutes so we try to avoid that wherever possible.

Comment: Where did you get this idea from? Shader compilation is a costly process (doing it over and over again on the same machine and getting the same result is rather pointless). Using precompiled (or at least cached) shaders is a recommended practice. For example look at [QUALCOMM dev network article](https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/binary-shaders)

Comment: @VTT: That's definitely a good thing to do. But you still have to compile your shader once on every new machine (and sometimes when the driver get's update), so the general problem stays. Also during development compiling the shaders at every start can be a necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few reasons:

- During development it's very convenient to 'hotload' shaders without restarting the application so you can make changes while debugging or performance tuning and instantly see the results. This is simpler when shaders are stored as separate files.
- As mentioned in the comments, depending on your platform it is common to precompile shaders from a high level shading language to an intermediate byte code representation or to actual final GPU code (e.g. in the case of consoles where the GPU hardware is a fixed target). Shader compilation can be quite time consuming so it is better to do it offline rather than at runtime when possible.
- The approach you take is actually not uncommon in small / simple applications, it becomes more painful the bigger your app gets and the more shaders you have to manage. Personally I like to be able to hotload shaders even on small personal projects.
- This is actually a more general question than just for shaders. In any project you have a choice of when to embed resources in the executable (either directly in source code or through a separate build step like Windows Resources) or store them as separate files. There are pros and cons to both approaches but the main advantage of embedding is that all the resources an app might need are embedded right in the executable so you don't have to worry about / deal with potentially missing resources. The downside is that if you cram everything into the executable (especially for a project with many large assets like a game) then you increase build times, make hotloading difficult and can make the problem of asset organization more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

How do you figure it would speed up load times? It doesn't!

It doesn't matter if you read data from a regular file that you opened with `fopen` (or `std::ifstream` or `CreateFile` or whatever) and read from that, or if you're accessing some part of the process image. Heck, in most cases accessing some large-ish hunk of pages in the process image may perform worse, because most OSs are lazily populating pages in the segments that hold nonexecutable, readonly data; mmaped read access on unpopulated pages is actually slower than just a plain read, because it involves faulting the page table and a subsequent I/O read to populate the page with data.

Mandatory read: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0004.0/0728.html

The OpenGL API specifices GLSL source code being the only way to actually load shaders. There's a caching API (glShaderBinary, glProgramBinary) but the binaries loaded through that are in an unspecified format, that may change at any time, and it's a valid error condition that the driver rejects a binary for whatever reason to enforce loading the original GLSL source. To actually obtain such a shader binary you first load a regular GLSL shader source, compile it and then retrieve a binary blob from OpenGL.

Comment: I said that because the process would already be sitting in ram vs reading from a file would be off of the disk. And the fewer the statements used to accomplish something will almost always result in the quicker code.

Comment: @KeithBecker: It's not working how you think. In a paged virtual memory environment the OS does not load the whole binary into RAM! That would be highly wasteful and is not necessary at all. What happens is, that a page mapping is created that works just like (in fact is uses the very same code path) as disk swap memory: The process file is essentially treated like a read only swap file and only those parts are pulled into RAM that are actually used. You can have a GiB large executable, if the code segment is just a few kiB it will load start just as fast as a tiny executable.

Comment: @KeithBecker: Anything that is not part of the code segment will actually not be loaded into RAM at all at launch. The OS creates a page mapping and when (if) you finally access it, those parts are pulled into memory. However this involves work than just reading directly into a buffer. Namely the relevant pages must be faulted, i.e. the memory manager must assign those pages some physical memory of the system (this is not a cheap operation, it's in fact rather slow).

Answer (score 0):

The shader compilation process is part of OpenGL's glsl compiler, while you can hardcore the shaders into memory as a string, it would require recompilation everytime you make ANY edit to the shaders.

In game programming you generally do not want to recompile the whole project when you are making small tweaks to hundreds of parts of the code, shaders, libraries, etc. This is one of the main reasons why all large game engines have scripting engines, it is often better to write extra boilerplate code to integrate scripting into your engine than have to compile a program 10 times just to get the color/shininess/position of your object just right. Try hardcoding all your shaders so they compile at runtime in memory and you'll see just how tedious it becomes after a day!